# Poor Performance in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, sorting

Looking for ways to improve the particularly bad performance I'm getting from my rails application. Here's the code from the page in question:

notifications_controller.rb

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @questions = Question.all.order(:updated_at => :desc)
    @users = User.all
    @answers = Answer.all.order(:updated_at => :desc)
  end
end
```

and here's the corresponding view. I know it's ugly but it's working.

```
<div>
<% if current_user %>
    <div class="notifications-added col-md-8">
        <h4 class="col-md-offset-2">Approvals &amp; Answers</h4>
        <span class="text-center">
            <% current_user.questions.order(id: :desc).each do |question| %>
                <% if question.approved == true %>
                    Your question, <%= link_to "#{question.title}", question_path(question) %>, has been <span class="notifications">approved.</span><br>
                <% end %>

                <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
                    <%= answer.user.name %> <span class="notifications">added an answer</span> to your question, <%= link_to "#{question.title}", question_path(question) %>.<br>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="notifications-voted col-md-4">
          <h4 class="text-center">Votes</h4><span></span>
          <% current_user.answers.order(updated_at: :desc).each do |answer| %>  
              <% @users.each do |user| %>
                  <% if user.voted_up_on? answer %>
                    <%= user.name %> <span class="notifications">upvoted</span> your answer to <%= link_to "#{Question.find(answer.question_id).title}", question_path(answer.question_id) %>.<br>
                  <% elsif user.voted_down_on? answer %>
                    <%= user.name %> <span class="notifications">downvoted</span> your answer to <%= link_to "#{Question.find(answer.question_id).title}", question_path(answer.question_id) %>. <br>
                  <% end %>
              <% end %>
          <% end %>     
        </div>  
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I think I'm just sorting too much. The page is taking a long time to load. What's the low hanging fruit for improving my performance? Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You define two variables `@questions, @answers`, but used `current_user.questions` and `current_user.answers` . why you need `@questions, @answers` variable if you do not use it?

Answer (score 1):

- The first , you should move logic code in your view into model.
- The second , use pluck method instead array active record objects. Array string are lightweight than array of active record. Right ?
- The third , use slim template engine instead erb template engine.
- The fourth , cache db.
- The fiveth, use google PageSpeed plugin for google chrome to analytic what's slow.

Answer (score 1):

Peter answer is correct, and I will add two things :

**Eager loading**

Doing this

```
current_user.questions.each do |question|
  question.answers.each do |answer|
    ...
  end
end
```

will generate a query for each question. Rails will load all the questions, then for each question load its associated answers (1 query + 1 query for any question).

If you replace the first line by

```
current_user.questions.include(:answer).each do |question|
```

Rails will load all the questions, then all the associated answers (2 queries).

**Look at the log**

Every information for any bad performance should be visible on logs in development mode. For example, if `voted_up` need to load any other models than `answer`, your query number will be too big.